# Pure Asynchronous Tasks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pure-function, folktale

*Combining [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) and [Folktale](https://folktale.origamitower.com/) functors*

`_fetchLists` is a function that performs an **async** operation, it takes the following arguments:

1. `fetchAlllists`: an async function that resolves with [Result](https://folktale.origamitower.com/api/v2.1.0/en/folktale.result.html) functor of an array of list objects
2. `listIds`: an array of listIds

   it `returns` a [Result](https://folktale.origamitower.com/api/v2.1.0/en/folktale.result.html) functor of an array of list objects

   - Is `_fetchLists` considered a pure function?
   - `fetchAlllists` is implemented to return a promise that resolves with a [Result](https://folktale.origamitower.com/api/v2.1.0/en/folktale.result.html), is there a benefit from using [Task](https://folktale.origamitower.com/api/v2.1.0/en/folktale.concurrency.task.html) functor instead of normal promise?

```js
const _fetchLists = R.curry(
  async(fetchAllLists, listIds) => {
    const lists = await fetchAllLists();

    return R.map(
      R.compose(
        R.values,
        R.pick(listIds),
        R.indexBy(R.prop('id'))
      ),
      lists
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: A function creating a promise is not pure because it starts the (often impure) work and uses a global scheduler, while a `Task` is purely representing the *capability* to do asynchronous work.